# webbrowser.open without getting rid of colon?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the webbrowser module to open a website, but it keeps getting rid of a colon after "steam".

```
import webbrowser

test = input("test: ")
webbrowser.open("http://steam://"+str(test))
#It removes it here          ^
```

But I also need the "http://" to be there, because otherwise it won't open.

Comment: I guess you meant a colon .... (bro please google *coma*)

Comment: I'd suggest explaining what you actually want to do instead of why the way you want to do it is not working. 

Because what you are specifying is a valid HTTP URL and because of that, an empty port is the same as no port spec at all (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-19)

Comment: `steam:` does not strike me as a valid hostname.